# How to search blob file by name in Azure Storage Explorer?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

Blob files in Azure storage explorer are paged, 100 files per page. Is there a way to search a file by name, so I don't have to go through pages to find it.

Answer (score 13):

The little filter icon on the right side when you are viewing a container is probably what you're looking for.

[image]

You can also select Flat listmode to show all of the blobs in the entire container in one list.

Just enter the front part of the name in the prefix filter and it will update in real time.

Comment: Is the filter still there? I can't find it (Mac OS version).

Comment: @Mori it's still there on the latest Windows version, but the icon changed to the filter funnel. Just click on the blob container and it should be at the top right next to the search bar

Comment: Thanks @joelforsyth. It seems to be not available in Mac version at all.

Comment: Dang, that sucks @Mori. You might be able to sell your Mac and buy two PCs though! ;)

Comment: Haha, not an option. It's not my personal laptop. Belongs to the company ;-)

Comment: Didn't get me all the way there, but this information was helpful regardless.